# How to change qml's SystemPalette globally in linux

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm using systemPalette (Qt5.15) in several qml-based applications in Linux, I need one of these applications to change systemPalette of qml system-wide (globally) so that other applications can detect this change at runtime.

what I need is similar to what happens in KDE, for example, I have the following qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SystemPalette {
        id: palette
        colorGroup: SystemPalette.Active
    }

    Rectangle{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: width
        color: palette.base

    }
}
```

when I run the above code in my KDE plasma, if I change the system's theme from breeze to breeze-dark, the rectangle's color will change at runtime, I can even select a custom color in
Appearance->globalTheme->colors.
In my case, regardless of Linux's distro, my application needs to change systemPalette globally and set its custom values for colors, how can I do that? where does qt read those color values from? (for systemPallete)

Thanks.

P.S: I can create my own style/plugin for qt and set different colors in my custom style, but still I have no idea how to change OS style globally so that all applications can detect this at runtime.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the OS's colors from within the Qt app?

Comment: @JarMan  somehow yes, but my app needs to run on embedded Linux as well with my custom desktop environment (based on Wayland), I need to have my own settings app which can change the system's overall color palette at runtime and other apps need to detect this change. in the above example, I'm using pure qt/qml and it doesn't depend on any KDE libraries, so it seems like there is a way to change the color palette for Qt-based applications globally at runtime. I'm still not sure how much that depends on the OS's structure. other workarounds like IPC or watching config files are not my interest.

Comment: Changing the colors in one Qt app will not affect the colors in another Qt app unless that app was made to be able to do that (through a config file or something).

Comment: @JarMan in KDE desktop when you change the system's theme, some config files are getting updated including the one in `~/.config/kdeglobals`, this file includes some color values that are set in the system. But in the above example, I'm not monitoring any config file, still, my app can detect this change and it gets updated at runtime (how?). my question is how I can change the system's colors without monitoring config files in every single application, however, it's okay to monitor/change config files in my settings app.

Comment: @JarMan to make it clear, imagine I have different apps including a shell,  file browser, image viewer, and a settings app, all running in Qt-Wayland in an embedded Linux, how can I change the system's theme in my settings app so that all other apps can detect this change at runtime(exactly like what KDE is doing)?  my settings app can create a config file and set some values in it, KDE is doing the same, however, I don't want all other apps directly monitor this file, KDE is doing this in a smart way so that even pure Qt/QML apps are getting updated(no KDE lib, no config monitoring, just QML)